# Why does scrollTop only scrolls half way down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have an error on a jQuery snippet and I am no jQuery expert.  I have a scrolling div which will auto scroll with the following function.

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function scroll(speed) {
        $('.shooter-scroller').animate({
            scrollTop: $(document).height() - $('.shooter-scroller').height()
        }, fast, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    speed = 15000;

    scroll(speed)
    setInterval(function () {
        scroll(speed)
    }, speed * 2);
});
```

I need to do 2 things with this script but would LOVE some help if people can help at all.

For some reason the scrolling stops halfway down the div and doesnt show all the content in the div and I would like to get the scroll to reset back to the top of the content once it has got to the bottom.  Is this possible at all?

Any help would be amazing!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andysimps1985/gn1a2kn7/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or at least html?

Comment: Hi, sorry, fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/andysimps1985/gn1a2kn7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
$(document).height() - $('.shooter-scroller').height()
```

to

```
$('.shooter-scroller').prop('scrollHeight')
```

That will give you the correct height.
See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1a2kn7/4/) (note: I changed the speed for a clearer result)

Comment: This works perfectly.  Is there any way to make it bounce straight back to the top once it gets to the bottom instead of scrolling back up?

Thankyou for the help by the way!

Comment: sure, just change the animation going up to `this.scrollTop = 0;` like http://jsfiddle.net/73f21nxw/

Comment: Just out of curiosity......the scroll seems to start off slow and then accelerate, is there anything that can be done to stop this at all?

Comment: The default easing pattern is swing (http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you can change that to `linear` to make it go the same speed constantly.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the bottom you have to give the scrollTop as the element's height.

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function scroll(speed) {
        $('.shooter-scroller').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.shooter-scroller').prop("scrollHeight")
        }, fast, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    speed = 15000;

    scroll(speed)
    setInterval(function () {
        scroll(speed)
    }, speed * 2);
});
```

This gets the scroll height.